# Cannot highlight all occurrences of a selected word in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-indigo

I tried using the `Toggle mark occurrences (Alt + Shift + O)` button and also in `Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editor -> Annotations` and setting the C/C++ Occurrences and C/C++ Write occurrences. But still when I select a word it won't highlight all occurrences of that specific word.

What I am using is Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2 in XP, with a C++ project.

Comment: The "Mark Occurences" options that everybody recommends will only highlight language tokens; it won't help you highlight a random word. See my answer for a 2016 possibility to highlight any word in any Eclipse pane.

Comment: @hmijail, in the new Eclipse Oxygen it works natively! check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42007441/658497

Comment: The glance plugin highlights any word in any pane, even if it is not an editor. The Oxygen functionality seems to just fix the highlighting that was broken or missing in JS editors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse doesn't highlight references anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919614/eclipse-doesnt-highlight-references-anymore)

Comment: I also tried 'Alt + Shift + O'. The answer given by Mark gives you the 'Toggle Mark Occurrences' button, which on hovering shows 'Shift + Alt + O'. So, your shortcut key sequence is incorrect.

Answer (score 293, accepted):

You can try to activate Toggle Mark Occurrences with icon on Toolbar:
[image: Eclipse Toolbar]

Comment: Ok, it seems this solution works when I create a simple new project, I tested on a big project and didn't work there don't know why.

Comment: This solution is used only to toggle Mark Occurrences. Before to this Mark Occurrences have to enabled.You can enable it  by going to Preferences --> Java --> Editor --> Mark Occurrences

Comment: This only worked after restarting eclipse.  Prior to that, it would only work if I first selected the word and then toggled it on.  I couldn't just keep it on.   Now it's fine.

Comment: This is great, do we have an option, after highlighting all occurrences, to edit/rename all of them at once?  Kind of like what visual code does (using cmd + d)  - please advise.  Thanks.

Comment: That is another question, but on Windows: Alt+Shift+R

Answer (score 37):

Preferences --> Java --> Editor  --> Mark Occurrences

Answer (score 21):

In `General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations`

[image]

Comment: Mine doesn't have the "Occurrences" option listed. Could it be because I'm using "Eclipse for Parallel Application Developers"?

Comment: very well explained and neat!

Answer (score 9):

Check out options that are checked in Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Mark occurrences. Then restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

The standard "Mark Occurrences" functionality included in Eclipse that everyone recommends only highlights *identifiers* in *editors* of whatever language. For example, it won't highlight `int` in C editors, and it won't help at all in the Console pane.

So if you want to highlight ALL occurrences on ANY word in ANY Eclipse pane (kinda like Notepad++ does), try the [Glance plug-in for Eclipse](https://ystrot.github.io/glance/).

As of November 2017 Glance works for Eclipse Neon and Oxygen. There was a period of time in which Neon was unsupported, and [a fork appeared](https://github.com/cypher256/glance), but it seems unnecessary now (and abandoned).

Comment: Sadly I have to press Ctrl+Alt+F to highlight all occurrences with the Glance Plugin, but it's better than nothing. I'm using Parallel Fortran and it doesn't even have the options suggested in the other answers.

Comment: And in addition to Ctrl+Alt+F you must also have the word or token selected first.
Nevertheless, better than nothing I guess. Such a feature is core in the majority of editors (but not Eclipse). Go figure.

Answer (score 4):

Find the `Preferences` under `Window`,

[image: main window - tab]

In `General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations`(1)

(5) is to select the color and press apply.

[image: Preferences window]

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to highlight all occurences. First is using Eclipse options, which is not very reliable, because in many versions of Eclipse it is not supported.
Second is using a plugin called [Glance](http://ystrot.github.io/glance/) which is available in Eclipse marketplace. This is supereasy and effective.

### First Method

In the toolbar, there is button for `Toggling Mark Occurrences`. So, once you selected the text/word whose occurences you wish to highlight, then click this toggle button.

[image]

Let's say this step doesn't work for you. Then, Follow this step:
Goto: `Window` ==> `Preferences` ==> `General` ==> `Editors` ==> `Text Editors` ==> `Annotations` ==> On right Annotations types box: `Occurrences` ==> Select all check boxes.
[image]

You can also go to `Window` ==> `Preferences` ==> `Java` ==> `Editor`==> `Mark Occurrences` ==> Check all the checkboxes.
[image]

Restart Eclipse and check if highlighting works.
If still doesn't work, then Go to Second Method

Second Method
From Eclipse marketplace, install `Glance`. Once installed, restart Eclipse.
Now select any word in your eclipse editor

1. Move focus to component where you want to search
2. Open Glance using `Ctrl + Cmd + F` shortcut on Mac or `Ctrl + Alt + F` on other platforms
3. Enter text you want to search
4. Use `Enter` or `**Shift + Enter**` to find next/previous match
5. Close search box using `Esc`
   [image]
   You can also customize Glance from `Window` ==> `Preferences` ==> `Glance`

Comment: "Glance" is no longer available/supported unless you find some old fork but then it probably won't work anyways in latest versions

Answer (score 2):

**For Eclipse Mars:**

Window --> Preferences --> Check (Mark occurrences of the selected element in the current file.)

**As shown if figure:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go

> Java> Editor > Mark Occurrences

Uncheck **"Keep Marks when the section changes"** then click **Ok**

*Restart Eclipse.*

This work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the window-prefrences, select the language you want/are working with. Select the editor under this specific language and then there is a mark occurrences there that has some options. Where it says keep marks when the selection changes, for me this was checked. When I unchecked it the system started highlighting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For folks who are using a dark background with light font colors, you may want to check out the highlight color in `Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editor -> Annotations`.  Mine was defaulted to black, which does not stand out on a black background.

Answer (score 0):

Glance does not work anymore, but in current Eclipse Versions (Eclipse 2020) you can
highlight any word by selecting the word and pressing **CTRL+F**. The word is now highlighted. In the small search input, you can toggle 'match whole word' and case sensitivity.

Comment: You would need also click "Select All"

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to complement the other answers - which work in Java editor only or require plugins - with a way to highlight all occurrences of any text (not just a word or identifier) in any editor of text files (e.g. SQL, CSV, HTML, TXT, Java, etc ...).

There is a standard/built in command called `Find Text in File` (under `Window -> Preferences -> Keys`)

[image]

By default it has no keyboard shortcut assigned. Simply give it a shortcut (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) select some text (not necessarily a word) and it will find and highlight all occurrences of that selected text.

It can also be invoked from the menu as `Search -> Text -> File`.
Enjoy

Answer (score -1):

1. Click the word and hold until a popup appears as shown in the figure.
2. On the popup, there is a little right arrow, after clicking it, a new icon shows up.
3. Click that link to open `preferences`.
4. Once in `preferences`, select `C/C++ Occurrences` (it will be language specific) and select `Include in next/previous navigation` with `Text as Highlighted`.

This should enable the feature of highlighting all occurences of the selected word in the opened file.

Comment: You might want to include the `figure` you are referring to.