# Automatic mark occurrences have stopped working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

For some reason since a day or two my mark occurrences in C/C++ code has stopped working.

It works when I toggle the button/shortkey (Alt+Shift+O). But once it is on it will not automatically update the editor when I select/click on a other field.

When I toggle the function off the highlighting goes away and when I then toggle it on again it will mark occurrences for the currently selected field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse mark occurrences doesn't mark all occurrences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188020/eclipse-mark-occurrences-doesnt-mark-all-occurrences)

Comment: (Should have searched before posting I guess)

Answer (score 1):

[This appears to be a bug in the Juno 4.2.2 release](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1008457/)

[Suggested workarounds on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188020/eclipse-mark-occurrences-doesnt-mark-all-occurrences/16031157#16031157)