# Highlighting occurrences in Eclipse PDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I'm working on a project that has now become complex enough to require navigational help from the IDE. In particular, I need highlighting of the occurrences of variables.

However, I can press the Toggle Mark Occurrences as many times as I want, PDT won't give me that useful functionality on anything, be it variables or functions. According to [this (old) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10310597/2749913), everything that is needed for that feature to work is correctly configured:

- In the preferences (General > Appearance > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations), all annotations types related to "Occurrences" or "PHP" have **Overview ruler** checked and **Text as** also checked, with a color set.
- In PHP > Editor > Mark Occurrences, every checkbox is checked.

This happens to me both in Neon.3 and in Mars.2: I'm not getting occurrences highlighted in PDT. JDT (Java) works as it should. CDT (tested on C++ code) works too.

Are there additional configuration options that evaded me?

Or is this a bug? I've searched the official Bugzilla and it seems that the highlighting of occurrences has been a recurring regression in Eclipse. It doesn't work either in JSDT (but that's a different issue because JSDT is undergoing an overhaul that caused a slew of regressions).

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me (sometimes still happens to me) but it improved significantly by adding more memory to my computer. It seems to be a functionality that due to the particularities of the php language requires many resources to be computed. I hope my experience will help you.

Comment: It also seems to help to enable fewer elements in the mark occurrence configuration.