# Make eclipse to highlight every other instances of selected text ? (like notepad++)

Tags: eclipse, ide, notepad++

In notepad++ when you select something, it highlights every other instance of the same thing.
in Eclipse I have to do the find, which is not pleasant, is there any way to make eclipse act like notepad++ when selecting?

Comment: This depends on the language you are editing. The Java editor, for example, can highlight uses of various elements.

Comment: I am writing java in eclipse, but when I select something it wont highlight all the identifiers automatically (like notepad++)

Comment: Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209423/how-to-fix-mark-occurrences-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for my question, ALT+SHIFT+O

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find this feature in the Eclipse configuration panel.